# CSS background-image only appears when I have image in same folder as the project index.css file

Tags: css, directory, path, background-image

Please forgive me if my jargon is a bit strange, as I am still a beginner with this stuff...

I am trying to open an image using CSS with a relative path. When I use the relative path to the image I want with "background-image: url()" the only way I can display the image is if the image is in the same folder as the main CSS file ("index.css"). If I move the image ANYWHERE else I cannot display the image.

EXAMPLE #1:

css(folder) -> index.css(main file), image.jpeg(image i want)

In the example above I can write "background-image: url(image.jpeg)" and the image will appear.

EXAMPLE #2:

HOWEVER, let's say I create another folder called "image_folder" inside the css folder that will hold the image:

css(folder) -> index.css(main file), image_folder(image folder that holds the image.jpeg)

In this example I write "background-image: url(image_folder\image.jpeg)" and the image doesn't appear.

**Why does the image only appear if I have the image in the same folder as "index.css"? I can't seem to put the image anywhere else and have it appear.**

Thanks

PICTURES:

[DOES NOT WORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go6H6.png)

[DOES NOT WORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYAtN.png)

[DOES NOT WORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cQM0.png)

[THIS DOES WORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aUL9.png)

[THIS DOES WORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6B7X.png)

[THIS DOES WORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKYP8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what I did differently this time, but as Debjeet mentioned, the forward slash in the directory path seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url(image_folder\image.jpeg)
```

This is your code, you have made a small mistake using backward slash `\`, your code should look like this:

```
background-image: url(./css/image_folder/image.jpeg)
```

use a single dot to locate its parent folder and navigate the image you want to display like I have shown. And use vs-code editor if you are not using vs-code, its a good software to write code and beginner friendly.

Comment: Thanks, but the back or forward slash does not appear to make a difference (nor does the period placement). The only thing I've found that works is if i put the image in the same folder as the project "index.css" file, and I'm still not sure why. I've added some pictures to the original post for more context

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem u have, make sure to define height and width when using background CSS property, or you can't see the image

Comment: The image appears when I change the location of the image file. The code does not appear to be the problem. I personally think it's the location and/or directory path I am using that is causing the issue of the image not appearing. I'm trying to figure out why the path I used in the example is not loading the image when I take the image from the index.css directory (see pics)

Comment: you should use another image or make another project and see if u have same problem.